# What econometric model would be use to study trade between a home country, and multiple foreign countries?

Tags: econometrics, panel-data, macroeconomics

While initally my proffesor and I thought a gravity model would suffice, we realized that the gravity model generally specifies only two countries in the textbook. Is their a gravity-type model for n foreign countries, and if so are their any articles I could look at? Would the gravity model still work, since I am looking at them in pairs?

My data is panel data for 61 countries over 30 years, if that is important to answering the question.

Comment: Can you be more specific? There seems to be a lot of papers that seems relevant, maybe start with [this one](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1112.2867.pdf)

Comment: FYI (just so you are not surprised), your question is one vote shy of being closed as unclear. You can still edit it to include more specific details. Besides, I think part of the reason it is unclear is that most of the people around here are more familiar with statistics than economics. Hence, the concept of the gravity model might need additional explanation.